# Why does the output give 43211234, instead of 43210

Tags: java, if-statement

This is a problem from the computer science A course [description](https://secure-media.collegeboard.org/digitalServices/pdf/ap/ap-computer-science-a-course-description.pdf) that I don't  understand.  I expected a value of 43210 because the if statement would reach 0 with (x%10), print it out, and then stop.

When I looked at the Eclipse debugger, I saw the value of x go from 1234, to 123, to 12, to 1... but then it showed the x values going back up to 12, 123, 1234.  So the actual output was 43211234.

The question: why does x values work their way back up to the original input?

```
public class Mystery
{
    public static void main(String []args){
        Mystery strange = new Mystery();
        strange.mystery(1234);
    }

    public void mystery(int x){
        System.out.print(x%10);
        if((x/10) != 0){
            mystery(x/10);
        }
        System.out.print(x%10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you printed before and after the recursive call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x=1234 print(4) <------|***

x=123 print(3) <------|**

x=12 print(2) <-------|*

x=1 print(1) print(1) 
Return -----|*

x=12 print(2) Return -----|**

x=123 print(3) Return------|***

x=1234 print(4)

To print 0 in end:

```
public class Mystery
{
    public static void main(String []args){
        Mystery strange = new Mystery();
        strange.mystery(1234);
    }

    public void mystery(int x){
        System.out.print(x%10);
        if((x/10) != 0){
            mystery(x/10);
        }
        else{
              System.out.print(0);
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public void mystery(int x){
    System.out.print(x%10);
    if((x/10) != 0){
        mystery(x/10);
    }
    System.out.print(x%10);
}
```

So, `mystery(1234)` will first print `1234%10` or `4`. Then whatever `mystery(123)` prints, then another `4`.

What will `mystery(123)` do? First print `3`, then whatever `mystery(12)` prints, then `3`.

What will `mystery(12)` do? First print `2` then whatever `mystery(1)` prints, then `2`.

And `mystery(1)` will print `11` without calling `mystery` again.

So now we know exactly what `mystery(12)` will do. First `2`, then `11`, then `2` again, or `2112`.

And `mystery(123)` we now know is `3`, then `2112`, then `3`. Or `321123`.

Putting it all together, we get `43211234`.